# argument count syntax error in Python

Tags: python, syntax

I'm getting a syntax error trying to make a Federated Table Builder.

Here's the offended interpreter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "federatedTableBuilder.py", line 7, in <module>
     local_public_files.generate()
  File "localViewDefinition.py", line 22, in generate
    self.generate_for_host(conn)
  File "localViewDefinition.py", line 17, in generate_for_host
    self.conn.doQuery(rsaconn,self.query)
TypeError: doQuery() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

and the offending code:

```
import mysql as sql
from connector import Connector
import io
import traceback

class LocalViewDefinition:

    ...insert variables...

    def doQuery(connection, query):
        try:
            cursor = MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor(connection)
            cursor.execute(query)
        except: #figure out how to handle generic and sql errors separately
            traceback.print_exc()
```

Do you have any idea about the cause?

Comment: You forgot to include the `self` argument when defining your `doQuery` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For class methods, Python takes an additional first argument to refer to the instance of the class. The convention is to use the word `self`:

```
def doQuery(self, connection, query):
      try:
          cursor = MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor(connection)
          cursor.execute(query)
      except: #figure out how to handle generic and sql errors separately
          traceback.print_exc()
```

This requirement to refer to the instance of the class is because "explicit is better than implicit" in Python (cf. `import this`).

Comment: Of course, there is something flaky about an instance method which doesn't use `self` at all ...

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have already covered the fact that your instance method needs to have `self`<sup>1</sup> as the first argument.  However, it is worth noting that an instance method which doesn't use `self` maybe shouldn't be an instance method at all ...

```
class Example(object):
    def instance_method(self):
        print "I need self: %s" % self

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        print "I don't need self."

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        print "I use the class, not the instance: %s" % cls

Example.static_method()  # I don't need self.
Example.class_method()  # I use the class, not the instance: ...
e = Example()
e.instance_method()  # I need self: ...
# can call staticmethods and classmethods from an instance as well:
e.static_method()  # I don't need self.
```

As a final word, staticmethods in particular aren't generally super useful.  Most of the time, a module level function without a class will due just fine.

<sup><sup>1</sup>The name "self" is just convention -- You *could* use any name you like, but I wouldn't suggest it</sup>

Comment: Are you sure you've indented consistently?  It sounds to me like you may have accidentally inserted a tab instead of spaces or something -- Although python3.x should have complained about that ...

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into IPython (running in SublimeREPL) and got my original results. I just typed everything in new, and it's working fine now. Strange. Oh well, never mind.

Comment: @MattDMo -- Ahh, sometimes copy/pasting code into the REPL doesn't work.  It assumes a blank line after indenting ends an indentation block I think ... usually, you need to copy into a file and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another argument - name it "self" - in the method definition.

```
def doQuery(self, connection, query)
```

Answer (score 0):

add self to def doQuery(connection, query)

def doQuery(self, connection, query):

that is the python class object reference.